# More than one data-config.xml or different import handlers in Solr?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I need to import several databases and rss sources using DIH.

Is there any possibility to use more than one *data-config.xml*? Or even if using only one, is there any way to configure different import handlers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple datasources in any DIH config.

If that doesn't cut it, you can create multiple request handlers in solrconfig.xml. One of the parameter of the handler configuration is "config" which defines the xml. So you could have --

```
<pre>
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str> 
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and ...

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport2"
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config-two.xml</str> 
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```